# How to send an email using javascript and not change the window location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, email

I have an image placed on the webpage.I want a simple JS code to open my default email client when the user clicks on the image.Now I looked up and found an answer and I tried this

```
var emailLink="mailto:" + img.email;
window.open(emailLink,'_self');
```

img.email gives the email I fetch from the response of a service hit.I do not want to open a new window or a new tab.The problem with this is,after doing this if I click anywhere on the webpage the email client opens up everytime.It looks like on every click I am executing these two statements each time.Can anyone provide a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var img = {
 email : "name@example.com"
};

var emailLink="mailto:" + img.email;

var a = document.createElement("a");      // Create an Anchor element
a.href = emailLink;                       // Set it's href
document.body.appendChild(a);             // Append to document
a.click();                                // Trigger a click()
a.parentNode.removeChild(a);              // Remove it
```

If you want a reusable **function** that passes an email string as parameter:

```js
function mailTo ( email ) {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = "mailto:" + email;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
}


// Call function like:
mailTo("name@example.com");
```

Comment: You beat me to it! I was thinking about doing it with an Iframe though: https://jsfiddle.net/w46om9tm/ :)